# Fisher's equation solution step

Tags: partial-differential-equations, biology

There is a step in finding steady states for fisher's equation that I cannot follow.

The equation is given as

$\delta_tu=D\delta_{xx}u+ru\Big(1-\frac{u}{K}\Big)$, where $D,r,K>0$.

The first step is to plug $u=\varphi(x-ct)$ into this equation.

The result is $-c\varphi'=D\varphi''+r\varphi\Big(1-\frac{\varphi}{K}\Big)$.

This step I do not understand. For example, putting $\varphi(x-ct)$ into $\delta_tu$ gives me $-c\varphi$ instead of $-c\varphi'$? $\big(\frac{d}{dt}\varphi(x-ct)=-c\varphi\big)$

Thank you for any help

Comment: Let $z(x,t) = x-ct$. Then you have $u = \phi(x - ct) = \phi(z(x,t))$. Hence, by the chain rule $$\partial_{t} u = \partial_{t} [\phi(z(x,t))] = \color{red}{\frac{d \phi}{dz}} \cdot \color{blue}{\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}} = \color{blue}{-c} \color{red}{\phi'(z)}$$

Comment: So, similarly $D\delta_{xx}u$ will reduce down to $D\varphi''$ with the chain rule. Thank you!